# Type of usage in these examples?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english

*That feeling you get when your kid won't let you do your housework.

*Me stressed at the thought of tonights traffic*.*

What do we call these types of sentences that commonly come with a picture or something that exaggerates a given situation.

And would the information after the comma be an absolute phrase here?

Sarah was miserable untill she met Steven, *a salesman who visits a company that makes your dreams a reality in this fantasy story which takes place on another planet.*

Answer (score 1):

These are all **noun phrases**, headed respectively by *feeling*, *me*, and *salesman*. Everything else in them is either a determiner (*that*, *∅*<sup>†</sup>, *a*) or a clausal modifier of the head: a reduced relative clause in the first, a participle clause in the second, and a frank relative clause in the third.

<sup>†</sup><sub>*me* is a pronoun, which is a sort of 'self-determined' noun; you might look at it as a 'fusion' of head and a null-determiner</sub>

Comment: What about this example:UK elections will be unfavourable, senior politicians have warned.

Comment: The first clause is internally a content clause and externally a complement of *warn*. In this fronted position it may represent an actual quotation or it may be a subordinate clause with the subordinator *that* omitted.